# Grails one-To-Many addTo() doesn't work?

Tags: grails, grails-orm, one-to-many

I have these domains:

```
    class ChildPlacementFile{
    .....
    static hasMany = [children : Client]
    static belongsTo  = [father : Client, mother: Client]
    Client child
    ...other fields etc.
    }

class Client{
String firstName
String lastName
....etc etc.
}
```

My client asked me to allow multiple save in the form. So I created a service that looks something like this.

```
def saveChildren(ChildPlacementFile childPlacementFileInstance, params){
    def childrenList = []
    def errorList = []

    params.rowId = [params.rowId].flatten()
    params.child = [params.child].flatten()

    params.rowId.eachWithIndex {child, i ->
        Client childInstance = Client.get(params.child[i])

        if(childInstance){
            childrenList.add(childInstance)
            childPlacementFileInstance?.addToChildren(childInstance).save()
                    }else{
            errorList.add(childInstance)
        }
    }

    [errors: errorList, children:childrenList]

}
```

When I try to check, on the controller, the children seems to be saved on the save() method[childPlacementFileInstance.?children], but when it redirects to the show() method, the [childPlacementFileInstance.?children] don't show up anymore, it's EMPTY. WHY?? O_O

There were no errors, no exceptions what so ever. So I expected that it worked, but it didn't. :(

Answer (score 0):

My guess would be that the save method fails on some constrains. Check after calling save check `childPlacementFileInstance.hasErrors()`.
If you wan't explicit exception to be thrown call method with parameter `childPlacementFileInstance.save(failOnError: true)`.

Comment: I did try to call failOnError: true, but it doesn't give me an error what so ever. Here is the line of methods it goes through: save() -> saveChildrenService() children seems to be saved -> redirect to show() in controller & children doesn't show up. It's just empty.

Comment: The only constraint I had for children is: children(nullable:true). I want the children to be optional.

Comment: I mean constraints for Client object. They are cascade saving so can fail too. You have no error though, so I don't know. Maybe post the exact full code you executing or upload it somewhere so I can check.

Comment: I didn't specify any cascade constraint to the client and ChildPlacementFile. Now that you mention it, maybe it's time that I should. I assume the business rules are that: 1. A ChildPlacementFile can only be deleted, when the Client(child) who owns the file is deleted. Mother, father, and children don't get deleted though, but their association with the file is killed. 2. When a childPlacementFile is deleted, the Clients(mother,father,child & children) associated with it are not deleted, but their associations are killed.

Comment: 3. When mother/father/children are deleted, the childPlacementFile should still exist. It's kinda confusing but can you help me add constraints to this?